# SSH to Switch and redirect the printout of command

Tags: python, redirect

I am trying to connect to switch and redirect the output of command but it does not work. It only connect and disconnect from switch

```
#!/usr/pkg/bin/python
#importing modules
import paramiko
import sys
import time

# setting parameters like host IP, username, passwd and port
# to gather cmds
HOST = "10.50.170.21"
USER = "user"
PASS= "password"
PORT = 2024

# A function that logins and execute commands
def fn():
    client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
    #add missing client key
    client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    #connect to switch
    client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS,port=2024)
    print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST
    stdin,stdout,stderr =client1.exec_command('show-config \n')
    print stdout.read()

fn()
```

and the printout like this :

```
root@cic-1:~# python test-con.py
SSH connection to 10.50.171.22 established
********************************************************************************
BSP 8100

This system is provided for authorized users only. If you are not
an authorized user, please exit IMMEDIATELY.
********************************************************************************

root@cic-1:~#
```

anybody knows what can be the issue here ?

Comment: Your code (updated for a host I can access) works for me. Perhaps it has something to do with the host you are connecting to.

Comment: I am connecting to switch and I should correct the code above as below 
stdin,stdout,stderr =client1.exec_command('show-config \n')

I do not have any problem to redirect the command prinout when the host is linux based but this does not work for switches

Comment: I have added debugging to the script   

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()

and I receive this error :
--Return--
> /root/test-con.py(31)<module>()->None
-> fn()
(Pdb) n
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <bound method DevURandomRNG.__del__ of <Crypto.Random.OSRNG.posix.DevURandomRNG object at 0x7f9947f65cd0>> ignored

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Code as below and now it works fine:

```
#!/usr/pkg/bin/python

#importing modules
import paramiko
import sys
import time
import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

# setting parameters like host IP, username, passwd and number of iteration
# to gather cmds
HOST = "10.50.171.22"
USER = "advanced"
PASS = "ett,30"
PORT = 2024
ITERATION = 3

# A function that logins and execute commands
def fn():
    client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
    #add missing client key
    client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    #connect to switch
    client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS,port=PORT)
    print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST

    remote_conn = client1.invoke_shell()
    remote_conn.send("\n")
    remote_conn.send("show \n")
    time.sleep(2)
    output = remote_conn.recv(10000)
    print output

#    stdin,stdout,stderr =client1.exec_command("config /n")
#    stdin,stdout,stderr =client1.exec_command("show /n")
#    print stdout.read()
    client1.close()    
fn()
```